# In Javascript, is it OK to put the ternary operator's `?` on then next line?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I really like aligning the ? and the : of my ternary operator when they don't fit on a line, like this:

```
var myVar = (condition
    ? ifTrue
    : ifFalse
);
```

However, [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) complains with:

> Bad line breaking before '?'

Why would JSHint have this warning? Is there any nastyness (like semicolon insertion, etc) it is protecting me against or can I safely change my JSHINT configuration to ignore it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works and is certainly valid. It's especially useful in more complicated use cases, like nested ones.

```
var a = test1
         ? b
         : test2
            ? c
            : d;
```

Comment: I know it works. I just want to be sure there isn't some evil Javascript nastiness behind that warning message.

Comment: @missingno: Not that I'm aware of, it even works with `return`, which sometimes ignores other lines.

Comment: This does help readability if you are nesting ternary expressions, but I would recommend variablizing the nested values, when possible, and using references to those variables in your ternary expression, which improves readability even more.

Answer (score 27):

**UPDATE**: This answer is outdated now. Apparently Crockford changes his mind ;)

See @CheapSteaks's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861468/244353) for the update.

Per [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html):

> Place the break after an operator, ideally after a comma. A break
>   after an operator decreases the likelihood that a copy-paste error
>   will be masked by semicolon insertion.

So:

```
// this is ok
var myVar = (condition ?
    ifTrue : 
    ifFalse
);
```

If you run this sample code through  JSHint, this will pass:

```
// this is ok
var myVar = (1==1 ?
    true : 
    false
);
```

Comment: Could you come up with an example of how semicolon insertion could bite me in this particular case? I already know what satisfies JSHint (I just don't like it...)

Comment: Well, if an auto insertion were to happen, this is valid: `var a = condition;` whereas this is not: `var a = condition ?;`. In the former case, that can lead to weird errors while in the later, you'll spot it immediately as all browsers will complain about invalid syntax.

Comment: The full quote is "Avoid excessively long lines. When a statement will not fit nicely on a single line, it may be necessary to break it. It is best to break after a { left brace, [ left bracket, ( left paren, , comma, or before a . period, ? question mark, or : colon.". That seems to be opposite of your interpretation.

Comment: What interpretation are you referring to?

Comment: If you follow the link you included, the recommendation of where to break lines is opposite of yours. Also the quote never appears. Perhaps the Crockford's recommendations changed?

Comment: @CeasarBautista I don't have any interpretation. The quote was taken ad verbatim at the time of OP. The documentation behind the scenes has changed it seems.

Comment: What *looks nicest to a human* is clearly what OP provided in his original example.  However, the problem is that it can potentially create the *dreaded semicolon insertion*.  To avoid that, as best as I can tell, @Mrchief 's answer provides the best compromise:  no semi- insertion, and relatively clean & readable.

Comment: This doesn't explain the question, which is _why_ it is bad to put a `?` on the next line. As far as I can tell, automatic semi-colon insertion couldn't happen because starting a line with a `?` is invalid syntax. Try `1;?2:3` and you will get a SyntaxError.

Comment: @redbmk Did you happen to pick this question because you had to downvote/flag something so that you could boost your stats and earn some medals?

Comment: @mrchief No need to take it personally. I came here wondering the same thing as OP. I downvoted your answer because I thought it could use some improvement, and left a comment that I hoped explained why. Your answer appears to be incorrect and also misquotes someone. The site you linked actually says you _should_ insert line breaks before question marks. Last I checked I actually lose points for downvoting something.

Comment: Actually Crockford prefers the operators on new lines  "The ternary operator can be visually confusing, so ? question mark always begins a line and increase the indentation by 4 spaces, and : colon always begins a line, aligned with the ? question mark. " http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 19):

Per [Crockford](https://www.crockford.com/code.html)

> The ternary operator can be visually confusing, so ? question mark
>   always begins a line and increase the indentation by 4 spaces, and :
>   colon always begins a line, aligned with the ? question mark. The
>   condition should be wrapped in parens.

```
var integer = function (
    value,
    default_value
) {
    value = resolve(value);
    return (typeof value === "number")
        ? Math.floor(value)
        : (typeof value === "string")
            ? value.charCodeAt(0)
            : default_value;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You should put the operator on the end of the line. That way its more clear that the statment continued to the next line.

Comment: This is subjective. I personaly find it clearer with the `?` on the next line.

Comment: @missingno - that is what jshint is trying to tell you.