# Rendering React components conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I am struggling to to render certain fragment of react component. This is how my component looks like:

```
import XYZ from './XYZ.js';

class ABC extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
      this.state = {
        showXYZ: false,
        showControl: false
      }
    }

  onshowClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showXYZ: true });
  };

  oncontrolClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showXYZ: true });
  };

  render() {
    return(
      {
        this.state.showXYZ
          ? <XYZ />
          : <div>
            <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
            </div> 
          <h1>Some text</h1>
          <p> More text </p>}
    )
  }
}
```

I want to render the same fragment when showControl is true also. Something like this:

```
return(
  {
    this.state.showControl
      ? <XYZ click = {this.props.oncontrolClick} />
       <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
      </div>
      <h1>Some text</h1>
      <p> More text </p> :null
  }
)
```

Now the problem is how can I handle these two together at a time. I tried to use logical operators but seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try [multi ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259065/in-javascript-is-it-ok-to-put-the-ternary-operators-on-then-next-line) like shown below.

```
this.state.showXYZ ? <XYZ /> :  this.state.showControl ? <XYZ  click = {this.props.oncontrolClick} /> : 
  <div>
  <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
  </div>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <p> More text </p>
        <div>
           <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
        </div> 
       <h1>Some text</h1>
       <p> More text </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to wrap else component in single div. Use this

```
<div>
  <div>
     <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
  </div>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <p> More text </p>
</div>
```

By the way You can use if conditions to make your life simple like :

```
render(){
if(this.state.showXYZ ||  this.state.showControl)
return(<XYZ click={this.state.showControl? this.props.oncontrolClick : null}/>) 

else 
{
return(
<div>
    <div>
      <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
    </div> 
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    <p> More text </p>
</div>
)
}


 }
```

Comment: I guess Yes if else is the possible best solution. But see for state showXYZ i want to render XYZ. But for showControl state I need to render the JSX also besides passing oncontrolClick function as a prop. As you can see in my example. In your solution it is returning XYZ for both states and JSX if else condition

Comment: I updated my question also!! Can you demonstrate accordingly!!

Comment: You mean, you want to show **<XYZ />** if showYXZ or showControl are true. otherwise else <div>

Comment: I want to render XYZ when state showXYZ is true and when state showControl becomes true, I want to pass some function as prop the to XYZ as well as render the JSX of component ABC, and do nothing when it is false as shown in  my example

Comment: You mean for **showXYZ** you want to show 
`<XYZ />`
For **showControl** you wan to show 
`<XYZ click = {this.props.oncontrolClick} />`

Comment: Yes as well as render all the JSX of component ABC for  ** showControl**

Comment: I edit my answer you can see it, now  **click** have method is  showControl is true else it is null

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one element from conditional statements. Either wrap them in div or React Fragment

```
return(
 <div>
  {
   this.state.showControl ? <XYZ  click = {this.props.oncontrolClick} /> :
   <div>
      <div>
      <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
      </div>
      <h1>Some text</h1>
      <p> More text </p>
   </div>
  }
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of Ternary Operators as just shortened if statements, using || should fix your problem:

```
return(
  <div>
    { this.state.showControl || this.state.showXYZ 
      ? <XYZ click={this.props.oncontrolClick} /> : 
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
      </div>
      <h1>Some text</h1>
      <p> More text </p>}
    } 
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 render() {
      return (
    this.state.showXYZ || this.state.showControl
      ? <XYZ click={this.state.showControl?this.props.oncontrolClick:()=>{}}/>
      : <React.Fragment><div>
        <Button onClick={this.onshowClick}>SHOW</Button>
        </div> 
      <h1>Some text</h1>
      <p> More text </p></React.Fragment>
)
```

}